# copy JavaScript object into class for faster performace

Tags: json, gwt

I'm using [Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes) and I wonder if it would be faster, to copy the JSON object into a class and access the fields there (so if I have a value: "hello" in my JSON file, I have a attribute "hello" in my Java class).

Will this bring a performance boost when using the same elements multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not (well, it of course depends what you do with the values).

It will boost your DevMode experience, as any JSNI method means some talking between the DevMode code server and your browser (through the DevMode plugin you installed there), but once compiled a field on a "POJO" is the same as a property on a JSO.